# Prevent Google App Engine from remembering session of non-admin user when using security-constraint

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, servlet-filters

I was going through **[this article](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Security_and_Authentication)** and got stuck with one issue. Imagine I have following rule in *web.xml*:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin access</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/AdminPanel.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Then non-admin user opens AdminPanel.jsp, GAE redirects him to Google Accounts login page, he  enters his credentials and logically gets this page

```
Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /AdminPanel.jsp from this server.
```

Now I can't re-login with another Google Account because I'm still authenticated as wrong user **and** GAE put **ACSID** cookie for app url. I will always get error message I mentioned above. Is there a way to elegantly solve this issue ? I'd like customer to be able to re-login with appropriate credentials. Also situation when customer is signed into more than one account is possible. I personally have Google Apps account and Gmail account. All Google applications such as GMail have options to Switch in between accounts. Can I do the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the user's credentials inside your app's servlet, rather than using `web.xml`. If they are logged in but not authorized, offer them the opportunity to log out.